# How to stop the calendar from sending emails to everyone?

Tags: mail.app, email, calendar, ical

I have a hotmail account configured in my calendar. Sometimes I receive ICS with events that include me and other participants (their emails). My problem is that if I try to delete the event, the calendar/hotmail sends an email to all participants even if I press "do not send it" when the calender asks. How can I prevent this?

Comment: What Calendar app are you using? iOS or macOS and which version?

Comment: MacOs Version 13.0 (2932.5.3)